# Rails: Advanced usage of FormBuilder

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, unobtrusive-javascript

I am working on our webapp and last week my task included implementation of a nested form that has dynamic field add removal feature (from associated child model). Note that the form implements two model with a one to many relationship. I researched on it and found out different ways, some of them adds/removes fields [without js](https://rbudiharso.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/dynamically-add-and-remove-input-field-in-rails-without-javascript/), where others uses js in the old way (rails 3 or before). I followed railscast-196 and [railscast-197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), but the helper method way explained is not unobtrusive way, right? (cause it's still using js in the html)

I am looking for a way to implement add/remove feature through jquery in a unobtrusive way.

Logically it should be possible through
- Making a ajax request to build an instance of the nested model,
- responding by building in server side through jquery,
- updating the view and then 
- sending the updated view back to client.

Problems:
- The problem that I am facing is passing the builder object to the jquery.
Expectation:
- Binding two custom add and remove field function to buttons in view through jquery

ADDITIONALLY: Could you please give me a link to a more in depth documentation to FormBuilder? Cause rubyonrails api doesn't explain enough. They don't even say that if you use form_builder.object, you will get the model (explicitly), let along ryanb's usage of FormBuilder "f.object.class.reflect_on_association".

Comment: You don't need to pass builder object to JQ, you use Javascript to load partial, which is plain HTML as rails responds to browser request with it

Comment: Joe Half Face: What about removal of a already existing and populated field?

Answer (score -1):

There's a gem that does expactly what you're trying to implement: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

If you want to make it manually here's the plan:

1. You don't need to send AJAX request to build instances of nested models (What happens, when user clicks add new instance button and closes the browser tab? The instance will stay in DB)
2. Use full power of Rails' [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) – it allows you to create parent and children models in one move, in one `create` or `save` call on parent model.
3. So all you need to do in JS is to create 2 buttons, one that adds some new fields, other that removes them. Just HTML, no AJAX calls.
4. To use nested attributes you have to stick to certain conventions when building params for `Parent.create` or `save`. Usually, when you create a model, you pass some attributes to the `create` method, those attributes correspond to the fields of the model. When you're using nested attributes you need to pass one additional attribute, which is formed in the following way: `[children_relation_name]_attributes`. So if you have `Project` and `Task` model and you want to create project and tasks simultaneously, you need to create them like so:

   Project.create(name: 'Project 1', tasks_attributes: [{name: 'Task 1'}, {name: 'Task 2'}])

(mind no ids for tasks – Rails will assign them automatically)

5. All the above works only if `Parent` model has `has_many :children` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :children`
6. So your task is just to build correct params that include `children_attributes` param, add this param to strong parameters (like so `children_attributes: [:name, :age, ...]`). You use `form_for` and `fields_for` to build form, JS to correctly put fields in this form, nested attributes to create parent and children records simultaneously. And this is what `cocoon` gem does.

As to Rails documentation, it's quite good and mostly comprehensive. Yep, no one's perfect and there might be some gaps, but there's nothing better than this documentation. You can also refer to Rails code but it's much more difficult than just to read documentation.